# How can I select a single account in Ganache?

Tags: web3js, truffle, dapp-development, javascript, ganache

Ganache (v1.2.3) provides a list of 10 accounts.

They can be easily selected by selecting `web3.eth.getAccounts();`.

However web3.eth.accounts[0] returns undefined as shown below. Not sure how to 
select just one account here.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of Truffle v5 uses web3 v1.0 which has [`web3.eth.accounts`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#web3-eth-accounts) as a module.

> The `web3.eth.accounts` contains functions to generate Ethereum accounts and sign transactions and data.

Another change in web3 v1 is that most functions are async and return a promise. To obtain a value you can `await` for it.

```
truffle(develop)> (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0]
'0x5f461C987879517f04a5Ae88A5B26CB6E9DB63bc'
truffle(develop)> addr=(await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0]
undefined
truffle(develop)> addr
'0x5f461C987879517f04a5Ae88A5B26CB6E9DB63bc'
truffle(develop)>
```

Comment: The code above worked as described.

Answer (score 2):

If it's Web3 1.x, it's a promise. Try:

```
> var accounts;
> web3.eth.getAccounts().then(function(response) { accounts = response; console.log(accounts[0]; });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If it's Web3 0.x then `web3.eth.accounts[0]` should actually work as is.

Comment: @RobHitchensB9lab                                                                                                                  
 I`m getting a "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".

Comment: Corrected a typo in line 2 `accounts`.

Comment: Corrected, still getting a `"TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"`

Comment: Hmmm ... try that. Edited.